# `getResources().getString` generating exception

Tags: android

In my application I have the following line:

`String ci = getResources().getString(R.string.cidades);`

This is throwing an exception while running the application. This only occurs in version 7.1 and 8 of Android, in the previous normal wheel, does anyone know why?

Logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.anestesiaanimal/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.anestesiaanimal.autenticacao.state}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>                                                                                                     at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
>                                                                                                     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:236)
>                                                                                                     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java:164)
>                                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:334)
>                                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:432)
>                                                                                                     at insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.anestesiaanimal.autenticacao.state.onCreate(state.java:38)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Where do you call `getResources`? Maybe you call this before it is made available?

Comment: @MattClark in onCreate, but this work in old versions :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround can be using `string-array` instead of `string`

```
<string-array name="items">
<item>item0</item>
<item>item1</item>
...
</string-array>
```

then

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
```

I dont know why but maybe your string exceeds the limitation of string resource in new Android versions

Comment: I'll try and tell you

Comment: How I get index this array?

Comment: Or does it come complete?